# Java JoptionPane trying to get it to work for sepreate method with double x4

Tags: java

i am trying to get my program to just show the grade and letter grade i know its a mess but i just need it to print but the Netbean says that JOptionPane requires double, double, double, double

```
package garrett_sprunger_a5;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Garrett
*/
public class Garrett_sprunger_A5 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString;       // For reader's input
        double     TestScore1,      //Define TestScore 1
        TestScore2,     //Define TestScore 2
        TestScore3,    //Define TestScore 3
        AverageScore; //Define AverageScore
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //To hold the users grade
                                                   // (somehow i am able to use
                                                   // keyboard but can't get the
                                                   // varible to match correctly)
        DecimalFormat formatter = 
                    new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0"); //format the scores
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputString=
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\t\nPlease enter Test Score 1");
        TestScore1 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
        // input TestScore2
        inputString=
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\t\nPlease enter Test Score 2");
        // Convert the input to a double
        TestScore2 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
        //input TestScore3
        inputString=
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\t\nPlease enter Test Score 3");
        // Convert the input to a double
        TestScore3 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
        //Calculate the average score for the tests
        AverageScore = Calcaverage(TestScore1, TestScore2, TestScore3);
        //AverageScore = (AverageScore +0.5);// applying midpoint roudning 
                                             // rule not needed with formated
                                             // rounding 
        //Display Average test Score
        {
            if(TestScore1 <0 && TestScore1 >100)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a Correct" +
                                                " data range between 0 and 100");
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\t\nYour Test Score 1  is : " 
                                            + formatter.format(TestScore1)  
                                            +"\t Grade: " 
                                            + getLetterGrade(TestScore1)
                                            + "\t\nYour Test Score 2  is : "
                                            + formatter.format(TestScore2)  
                                            + "\t Grade: "
                                            + getLetterGrade(TestScore2)
                                            + "\t\nYour Test Score 3  is : " 
                                            + formatter.format(TestScore3) 
                                            + "\t Grade: "
                                            + getLetterGrade(TestScore3)
                                            + "\t\nYour Average Score is : "
                                            + formatter.format(AverageScore)
                                            + "\t Grade: "
                                            + getLetterGrade(AverageScore));
    }//End main method

    public static double Calcaverage(double TestScore1,
                                double TestScore2, double TestScore3  ) {
        double AverageScore = ((TestScore1 + TestScore2 + TestScore3)/3);
        return AverageScore;
    }

    // Determine the letter grade

    public static char getLetterGrade(double TestScore1,
                double TestScore2,double TestScore3, double AverageScore) {
        if (AverageScore >=90) {
            return 'A';
        } else if (AverageScore >= 70 && AverageScore < 90) {
            if (TestScore3 > 90)
                return 'A';
        } else
            return 'B';

        if(AverageScore >=50 && AverageScore <70) {
            if(((TestScore2 + TestScore3)/2.0) > 70)
                return 'C';
        } else 
            return 'D';
        if (AverageScore < 50)
            return 'f';
           else 
               return '0';
    }

    public static void displaygrade( double AverageScore,
                            double TestScore1, double TestScore2,
                            double TestScore3, char getLetterGrade) {
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\t\nYour Test Score 1  is : " +
                                             formatter.format(TestScore1)  +
                                            "\t Grade: " + getLetterGrade(
                                            TestScore1) +
                                            "\t\nYour Test Score 2  is : " + 
                                            formatter.format(TestScore2)  +
                                            "\t Grade: " + getLetterGrade(
                                            TestScore2) +
                                            "\t\nYour Test Score 3  is : " +
                                            formatter.format(TestScore3)  +
                                            "\t Grade: " + getLetterGrade(
                                            TestScore3) +
                                            "\t\nYour Average Score is : " + formatter.format(AverageScore)+
                                            "\t Grade: " + getLetterGrade(
                                            AverageScore));
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the error is `getLetterGrade` requires `double, double, double`, which you've defined the method as needing...

Comment: ok... so do i change the getLetterGrade?

Comment: Either you need to change the requirements of the `getLetterGrade` method to accept one `double` parameter or pass if 4 doubles when you call it

Comment: i appreciate the timely response but that does not help me with the code i am a beginner at this and am trying to understand how to get this to work... sorry i'm a little slow and frustrated

Comment: how would i pass ' if ' 4 doubles when the code calls it? or get it down to one single 'double'

Comment: Look at the requirements of your `getLetterGrade` method, it needs `TestScore1, TestScore2, TestScore3, AverageScore`

Comment: Please format your code properly. Within NetBeans you can use `Format` to do so. It is really hard to read and therefore to understand.

Comment: i see that getLetterGrade method needs ts1- 3 and AverageScore ... but i don't know at way to make it any easier at the moment

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you change the `getLetterGrade()` method to something which resembles this:

```
public static char getLetterGrade(double testScore) {
    if (testScore >= 90) {
        return 'A';
    }
    else if (testScore >= 80) {
        return 'B';
    }
    //continue using if statements to determine the letter grade
}
```

Note that the method above only has one parameter, `double testScore`, which should be more helpful than inputing four doubles at once.

Would also like to point out that this `if` statement in your code will never run. Should be easy to figure out why:

```
if(TestScore1 <0 && TestScore1 >100)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a Correct data range between 0 and 100");
```

Comment: As @psaenger mentioned, it is also a good idea to format your code properly for ease of reading. It will make finding errors easier.